# How do I access only first element in nested dictionary in Django template?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-templates

I'm trying to print only first key and value of nested dictionary in Django. I am able to do this with python but in Django template language my logic isn't working.

**Here is my code in DTL**

```
    {% for key, value in data.items %}
        <h1>Dictionary: {{ key }}</h1>
     {% for key, value2 in value.items %}
     <h3>Nested Dictionary-> {{ key }}: {{ value2 }}</h3> <!-- Its printing complete nested Dictionary-->
     {% endfor %}
```

Here is my view.py which takes data from api then converts json to dictionary

```
def home(request):
    res = requests.get('https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/countries/india')
    data = (res.json()) 
    print(type(data))
    return render(request, 'Caraousel/home.html', {'data':data})
```

Here is my output screen. As you see I want to print only value: number
[image: Django Template]

Don't get confused by nested loop it need because there is nested dictionary:

[image]

Comment: What is the use of the nested loop if you only want the value:number pair from every key in the dictionary? Also, avoid using the same name for `key` for both loops

Comment: I'm using nested loop because the data I want is inside a nested dictionary. Please see updated question it shows original JSON data which I am converting to dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is your data:

```
'Dictionary: confirmed': {'value': 10937320, 'detail': 'https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/countries/india/confirmed'}
    
'Dictionary: recovered': {'value': 10644858, 'detail': 'https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/countries/india/recovered'}
    
'Dictionary: deaths': {'value': 155913, 'detail': 'https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/countries/india/deaths'}
    
'Dictionary: lastUpdate': 2021-02-17T18:23:40.000Z
```

You can process your data for your need before rendering in template. So let's update our nested dictionary to hold values for first item:

```
def home(request):
    res = requests.get('https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/countries/india')
    data = (res.json())

    for key, value in data.items():
        if type(value) is dict:
            # Create iterator to get only first item from nested dictionary
            item_iterator = iter(value.items())
            first_item = next(item_iterator)

            # Update key containing only first item
            data[key] = {first_item[0]: first_item[1]}
    
    return render(request, 'Caraousel/home.html', {'data':data})
```

The data will be like this after this processing:

```
{'confirmed': {'value': 10937320},
 'recovered': {'value': 10644858},
 'deaths': {'value': 155913},
 'lastUpdate': '2021-02-17T19:23:59.000Z'}
```

Now you can get what you need with your existing code.

Comment: Hey thank you so much for your efforts but I guess my image is vague to understood please have a look again I updated. First Confirmed is dictionary inside there is another dictionary having value: numbers, detail:url.

Comment: How about processing data before rendering it in template?

Comment: @NehaSharma edited answer, check if this solves the issue

Comment: I just did same and then I came here to update but just saw your answer lol. Thank you our logic is almost same and it's working properly. I appreciate your help :-)